Why can I brush particles with density brush on the subdivided cube i made, but not this model I imported from Daz?
My apologies for not posting gifs of the issue directly on the post here, my gifs are unfortunately bigger than 2mb and wont post. You can view the gifs of my issue here, and my blend file can be downloaded here
Trying to follow this tutorial to add hair to Daz3D characters I have imported to blender with Diffeomorphic, and I'm running into an issue right at the first step about lol.
As you can see in the gifs, I add an Empty Hair Curve to the subdivided cube head I made, and was able to add hair particles in sculpt mode using the density brush no problem. However, when I try to do this to my Daz character you can see the sculpt brush stroke is alot more laggy, and adds less hair that looks much bigger.
I noticed a few thing which might help you guys figure this out:

First and most obvious is my character is from daz and imported with diffemorphic, meaning the character imported came fully rigged, whereas the tutorial project uses an unrigged head model found online

Adding an empty curve hair to the subdivided cube head I made showed the hair curve coming up under the cube, in the outliner, make it appear to be parented to the cube. When adding the empty hair curve to the character, it doesnt do this

The UV for the top of the head/scalp is split into two different sections in the UV map, which is highlighted in the last gif.


Any help is super appreciated, this help would be huge I'm super excited to try this new hair system out!

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images even if the gif won't fit, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
